# Image array repeating/duplicating in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

The problem is as shown in the image I've attached, my first day learning php and sql.

I want the images to be assigned to each particular item, so first item picture be displayed above the first item described rather than all 5 of them above each description. I'm still very new to this sorry. Thank you!

[image]

My code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("xxxx", "xxxx",
                     "xxxx", "xxxx");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM MyShop WHERE ID BETWEEN '1' AND '5'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $array = array("cp.jpeg", "BV-C.jpeg", "BV-B.jpeg", "ADIY.jpeg", "CDG.jpeg",);

    while($person = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach( $array as $image ){
        echo "<img src='" . $image . "' height='200' width='200'/>";
    }
        echo "<center><h3>" . $person['Name'] . "</h3><center>";
        echo "<center><p>" . $person['Colour'] . "</p><center>";
        echo "<center><p class='ex'>" . $person['Description'] . "</p><center>";
        echo "<center><p> £" . $person['Price'] . "</p><center>";
}



?>
```

Comment: Don't loop in the `while`, use the `id` (minus 1) as the index. You would probably be better off storing the image locations in your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All five images are getting displayed first because your foreach loop closes after the img tag.

So it is printing each image, and then displaying your item information. Try this and see if it fixes your issue.

```
$count = 0;
while($person = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<img src='" . $array[$count]. "' height='200' width='200'/>";
    echo "<center><h3>" . $person['Name'] . "</h3><center>";
    echo "<center><p>" . $person['Colour'] . "</p><center>";
    echo "<center><p class='ex'>" . $person['Description'] . "</p><center>";
    echo "<center><p> £" . $person['Price'] . "</p><center>";
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: I tried that before, it worked but the issue was each loop was repeating 5 times, so instead of each description occuring 5 times, it occured 25 i.e. item 1 ='X', item 2='Y' .... would appear XXXX YYYYY ZZZZZ, so the images loop correctly, except each name, description and price repeats 5 times, then the next one repeats 5 times

Comment: See my updated answer. It may be easier for you to store the image links in the database with the rest of the details to avoid having to deal with a separate array, this way you can get all the information from $person.

Comment: Thank you so much! worked, I understand now, it would of probably been easier indeed to store the images in the database.

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes if the image file name was stored in the database you could just access it via $person['image'] for instance, which is a lot neater as you can get rid of your images array you have separately.